# changing a complex number into $a+bi$ form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I saw a puzzle online today that read the following:

"Write the complex number $\frac{z+2i}{iz+3i}$ in the form $a+bi$"

I have tried multiplying by the complex conjugate and exponentialising the fraction but neither seem to help in putting it into cartesian form.

EDIT 1: Thank you for all the replies.  Yes I mean for $z$ to be a complex variable.

EDIT 2: I have tried to reply to a user called @complexmanifold who tried to help initially. I told him that I did not know how to get from his second to his third line of working and I got voted down.  I am sorry I am just trying to learn.

Comment: What exactly is $z$?

Comment: Please see the [MathJax reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What do you mean by exponentiating? All you have to do is to multiply by the conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: You could show us your steps when you tried to multiply by the complex conjugate, since this will make it easier to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: $z$ is often used for complex variables. Did you mean for it to be a real variable here?

Comment: @Floris Claassens It is a complex variable.  I asked a further follow up question to a user called complexmanifold and they downvoted me because of a lack of research effort.  I am just trying to get some help and doing my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know when you divide two complex numbers such as $\dfrac {2+3i}{4+5i}$, the standard thing is to just multiply by $\dfrac {4-5i}{4-5i}$ and this is guaranteed to work, because it is guaranteed to give you a real number in the denominator. Then it's just a matter of computing the multiplication on the top.

This problem is no different. Write $z$ as $x+yi$ (a technicality: I'm trying to avoid using $a, b$ since the directions say to write it in the form of $a+bi$, so the $a$ and $b$ should be the real and imaginary results of the *answer*, not of $z$).

So back to the topic; replace $z$ with $x+yi$ and then collect terms:

$$\dfrac{(x+yi)+2i}{i(x+yi)+3i} = \dfrac{x+(y+2)i}{-y+(x+3)i}.$$

And now it's a division problem just as in the beginning of the answer. So you can apply the same method.

And yeah this is the way to do it whenever you've got a division of two complex numbers, no matter if they are written in terms of $z$ like your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

\begin{align}
\frac{z+2i}{iz+3i} &= \frac{-i(z+2i)}{z+3} \\
&= \frac{2-iz}{z+3} \\
&= \frac{[((a+3)-bi)(2-i(a+bi))]}{(a+3)^2+b^2} \\
&\vdots
\end{align}

Comment: @Masacroso Yes I do, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I understand how to get from line 1 to line 2 (multiply top and bottom by $-i$) but I do not know how to get from there to the third line or how to continue from there.

Comment: @puzzled They wrote $z=a+bi$ and then multiplied the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of $z+3=(a+3)+bi$

Comment: @puzzled Yes that is what I did as suggested by Peter. The rest is elementary algebra.

Comment: @complexmanifold

multiplying out the top line gives $2a-(a^2)i+ab+6-3ai+3b-2bi-ab-(b^2)i$ which looks like the equation of a circle - correct?

Comment: @Peter Foreman as complexmanifold has not replied for almost 24 hours, would you be able to offer an idea as to what the next step may be? I feel that the above multiplied-out expression may factorise, but not sure exactly how or indeed whether this would even help in solving the problem asked.  Perhaps at this point I am supposed to just separate the terms into imaginary and real?  Honestly not sure how to continue. Any help?

Comment: This simplifies to $$\frac{z+2i}{iz+3i}=\frac{(2a+3b+6)-(a^2+b^2+3a+2b)i}{a^2+b^2+6a+9}$$ so clearly the real and imaginary parts of this number are given by $(2a+3b+6)/(a^2+b^2+6a+9)$ and $-(a^2+b^2+3a+2b)/(a^2+b^2+6a+9)$ respectively.

Comment: And this would be as simplified an answer as it is possible to give in this case? 
 I thought there would be some trick to make it look more "neat and tidy" but I guess at this level solutions are not as simple as one might like, Thanks for the help complexmanifold and @Peter Foreman :)

Comment: @puzzled I don't see a way to simplify that; but even if there is a clever trick that we're missing, it's not really important. The important thing is that that is the right answer. Simplifications can make it more aesthetically pleasing, or easier to compute if you are given concrete values for $a$ and $b$, but that's about it. The important thing is, that's the right answer for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The real and imaginary parts of the solution are given by $(2a+3b+6)/(a^2+b^2+6a+9)$ and $(a^2+b^2+3a+2b)/(a^2+b^2+6a+9)$ respectively.  Evidence of my research and workings done by others is shown in the comments on this page.  Thanks to users complexmanifold and Peter Foreman for helping greatly to solve this problem.